# Is it dangerous to charge gadgets at less than 5 V?

Tags: voltage-regulator, battery-charging, dc-dc-converter, solar-cell

I'm using a solar panel, which gives me unstable current (from 0 to 9 V approximately), then I use a step-up converter to increase te voltage a little (my goal is to keep it between 7 and 12 V in sunny or cloudy weather). Following that is an LW7805. As a result I have a voltage from 0 to 5 V, depending on weather conditions

Is it dangerous to charge gadgets (phone, power bank, e-reader) at this voltage (<= 5 V)  or I can just directly connect them to the LW7805? I know that at some current level the phone will stop charging, but will lower voltage damage it?

If it dangerous, how can I filter it so there would be only 0 or 5 V?

Comment: Explain how do you understand "dangerous".  Why low voltage may damage your devices? It could be not charged.

Comment: By dangerous I mean Is it crucial for gadget's electronic and battery

Comment: Too low a voltage and it won't charge, too high and it may be permanently damaged. The actual voltage range depends on the device.

Comment: It makes no sense to boost up and then use a linear regulator to bring the voltage down to 5V. 7805 needs around 7.5V in to work so efficiency is terrible. Also devices either take charging current they want or they don't work, so you can't just charge a little. If a device says it charges at 1A it will take 1A and if it is not available then 7805 output drops and there is not enough voltage to charge.

Comment: Use a buck boost converter and wire up the enable pin so that it turns off if the source voltage gets too low (e.g. at night time).

Comment: @Justme IIRC some devices do slow down charging based on voltage drop.

Comment: using a 7805 will waste much of your energy. It is better to use a buck DC-DC converter to bring your 7-12 volts down to 5V. You can do even better though, with a MPPT 5V converter. It will draw current from your solar panel in such a way as to draw near the maximum power available, and then convert it to your desired 5V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With most gadgets, charging uses inherently unidirectional power conversion, so if the input voltage is too low, the battery will be isolated from the input. So I doubt that any damage will occur.

There may be a low-cost gadget or two that could back-flow the current from the battery to the USB power input - that's easy to check for. Power it from an adjustable supply, add a load resistor - say 100 ohms - and make sure there's no negative current flowing back into the supply.

The power conversion you've set up is very wasteful as well. You should use a buck-boost converter that outputs 5V directly, with no additional regulators needed.

Or, if you want a simple solution, just put a few 5V2 Zener diodes in parallel to shunt the high voltage from the solar cell. Make sure you got enough of them to dissipate about 40% of the solar cell's maximum output power. Then, the output will be regulated down to just above 5V, and the more load there is from the devices, the less energy will be wasted by the Zener diodes. This is the simplest solution that offers reasonable efficiency - but the solar panel may not be most efficient at 5V output. To get most out of it, you'd definitely want a buck-boost converter.